# To develop a side menù bar like Gmail Android App

Tags: android-layout, material-ui, material-design, material-components-android, android-design-library

Which is the component used to develop the side bar on Gmail Android App ? It seems a Navigation rail but animated like a Navigation drawer.
I have tried to put the two component in the same layout, but the transition between the rail to the drawer is not so good.
I want to recreate the same effect of gmail but I don't know how.